# Numpy FFT (Fast Fourier Transformation) of 1-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, fft

I have a simple one-dimensional array like `[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]` which describes a square impulse. I would like to transform this impulse to the frequency domain and plot its magnitude spectrum by using the code below (I got it from [OpenCV Python Tutorials](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_transforms/py_fourier_transform/py_fourier_transform.html)):

```
squareimpulse = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])

img = (squareimpulse)
f = np.fft.fft(img)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
magnitude_spectrum = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Magnitude Spectrum'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

The script works fine for two-dimensional arrays with `f = np.fft.fft2(img)` but not for my case where I only got one dimension.

Hope we can figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `plt.imshow(.....)` into `plt.plot(.....)` and the script is now working!

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    squareimpulse = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])

    img = (squareimpulse)
    f = np.fft.fft(img)
    fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
    magnitude_spectrum = (np.abs(fshift))

    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.plot(img)
    plt.title('Input Image')
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

    plt.subplot(122)
    plt.plot(magnitude_spectrum)
    plt.title('Magnitude Spectrum')
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
plt.magnitude_spectrum(img)
plt.show()
```

Well, seriously, the `imshow` function doesn't accept just a list of values. See http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow